# «Орангутан» или «орангутанг»?

Tags: этимология, орфография, транскрипция, заимствования

Как правильнее: "орангутан" или "орангутанг"?
Как-то привычно по всевозможным энциклопедиям написание "орангутан". Но тут увидела на docs.google в чате "Неопознанный орангутанг". Засомневалась.

Comment: Какие энциклопедии конкретно? Викисловарь:орангутанг - то же что орангутан. Словари на Грамоте: ОРАНГУТАН; ОРАНГУТАНГ, -а; м. [малайск. orang utan - лесной человек]. Крупная человекообразная обезьяна (обитает на островах Суматра и Калимантан). Наверно, орангутан - предпочтительнее, раз стоит первым.

Comment: Исходя из малайского словосочетания, вероятно, все-таки "орангутан". А "орангутанг", наверное, появилось уже как не вполне корректная транскрипция? Но все же такое написание тоже считается верным.

Answer (score 4):

Точно не помню, но вроде бы орангутанг - более древняя норма. 
Сейчас и в русском, и в других языках она повсеместно вытесняется более короткой.

А вообще один вариант пришел из английского, в котором носовой согласный Н передаётся сочетанием ng, передаваемом в русском аналогичным нг, а второй - из французского, при заимствованиях их которого непроизносимые конечные согласные обычно не отображаются (кроме н, которая иногда сохраняется).

Comment: Насчет природы заимствования интересно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно - орангутан. А "орангутанг" стало нормой, как "кофе" среднего рода, вследствие массового употребления безграмотной формы. Образованные люди все равно говорят "орангутан" и "крепкий кофе".

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии не поместится, поэтому попытаюсь изобразить ответ.
Участник *@Олег*:

> Когда я учился в школе, это ещё середина 70-х, в одном из журналов "Вокруг света" (точно не помню, вроде бы в нём) прочитал, что правильно "орангутан", а "орангутанг" на малайском значит "человек-должник".

Нашла я этот "вокругсветовский" выпуск (**июль 1977 года**): [МОГУТ ЛИ ГОВОРИТЬ «ЛЕСНЫЕ ЛЮДИ»?](https://www.vokrugsveta.ru/vs/article/5513/)

Нет там никаких "человеков-должников", а есть просто **орангутан, орангутаны**.

> Имя этих обезьян образовано из двух слов: «orang» — «человек» и «hutan» — «лесной». А поскольку **орангутаны**, пусть даже лесные, но все же «люди», они должны уметь говорить, утверждают легенды. В конце концов, разве **орангутаны** не сооружают себе из веток удобные постели на верхушках деревьев и не укрываются во время дождя большими листьями-одеялами? Разве не растут у самцов усы и борода, как у человека? Разве **мамаши-орангутанши** не баюкают своих малышей, не расчесывают им нежно шерсть и не купают под теплым дождиком? Ведь все это требует куда больше ума, чем обычно предполагается. Другое дело, что **орангутаны** очень хитры...

Comment: Не имею возможности писать подробно, тезисно. Вопрос не в том, что есть в этом самом "вокруге", все равно не авторитетный источник. О том, что orang utang переводится как "должники" не говорил только ленивый, гугл-переводчик это косвенно подтверждает, давая именно такой перевод. Но вопрос-то в том, можно ли этим обосновывать правильность одного варианта против другого. Тут же не транслитерация определяющая, а фонетика, а иногла и традиция. Первой мы не знаем, а вторая ставит орангутанга вровень с орангутаном.